# Suggestions to improve my solution to the question: "Does the unique solution of $\frac{dy}{dx}=(|y|)^{\frac 12},y(0)=0$ exist ? Justify."

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing

Does the unique solution of $\frac{dy}{dx}=(|y|)^{\frac 12},y(0)=0$ exist ? Justify.

This problem looks trivial but I am bit unsure about how I reasoned out things. Here it is:

Given, $\frac{dy}{dx}=(|y|)^{\frac 12},y(0)=0.$

So, we have, $\frac{dy}{|y|^{\frac 12}}=dx\implies x+c=2|y|^{\frac 12}\implies (x+c)^2=4|y|.$

If $y(0)=0$ then, $c=0.$ So, our particular solution,  is, $x^2=4|y|.$

But $y=0$ i.e the $x-axis$ is a solution  as well, that is not represented by the particular solution $x^2=4|y|.$ Hence, we claim, that the equation does not have a unique solution.

---

But somehow, I feel that  this is clumsy. Is there anything I can do to improve this?

Last but not the least, if there are any errors in my solution please do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $$\dfrac{dy}{|y|^{1/2}}=dx$$ you supposed $y\not\equiv 0 $. So you have multiple solutions and this isn't in contraddiction with Picard–Lindelöf theorem because the Lipschitz hypothesis is not verified.
So your solution is correct but it seems that $y=0$
come up without any reason. Indeed, your reasoning avoid thit solution because you divided by $y$ (i want only to motivate why your reasoning exclude that solution). Be careful because if you didn't notice that y=0
is a solution, you will claim that the solution is unique.

Comment: I am sorry, but you have not added any context as to whether my approach is correct or not. It seems that you punched down some lines (admittedly on this topic,)  but without any clear reference as to what are they pointing at in my post!

Comment: Your solution is correct but it seems that $y=0$ come up without any reason. Indeed, your reasoning avoid thit solution because you divided by $y$ (i want only to motivate why your reasoning exclude that solution). Be careful because if you didn't notice that $y=0$ is a solution, you will claim that the solution is unique.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I accepted your answer. But you might consider adding your comment to the answer, as it will serve to make the answer more complete.